# How to reword to make it on topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/267150/meterpreter-execute-command-options?noredirect=1#comment553650_267150) got closed for being "off topic". The [Help Center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically says "security tools" are in scope. I don't understand why asking about how to use a tool is out of scope and I'd like help revising the question to bring it in scope.

Comment: Asking about how to use a tool is not off-topic, but asking for detailed documentation on the entire capabilities of a large and complex tool is definitely out of scope of the site.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, we can't provide a full manual on all the different options. You need to narrow down what specifically you don't understand, and, for instance, what more you are looking for from "-i allows us to interact with the process after we create it"